# How to verify nonce from Bulk/Quick Edit in save_post?

Tags: ajax, save-post, bulk, nonce, quick-edit

I need to do something specific in my `save_post` callback for bulk and/or quick edits, so how do I check the nonce for that? I can only find `_wpnonce` in the `edit.php` html source, but can't find an action to match it with. I also tried `check_admin_referrer()` (no arguments) but it fails.

1. What nonce whould I check for? OR
2. Should I check for something else in `save_post` to know it's being fired from a

   a. bulk edit or

   b. quick edit action? I read that `DOING_AJAX` is there for quick edit, but is that enough on its own? what about for bulk edit?

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: select an answer from below as correct answer. If any of these isn't the right answer. Write an answer and select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `check_admin_referer('bulk-posts')` in wp-admin/edit.php:49 for bulk edit. With @Rutwick Gangurde's help, I found `check_ajax_referer( 'inlineeditnonce', '_inline_edit' )` in wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php:1318. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Why did you copy over @RutwickGangurdes answer instead of marking his as solution?

Answer (score 9):

It's `inlineeditnonce`. Check line 1185 of `admin-ajax.php` for details.

Comment: ok, i searched for `inlineeditnonce` and found  `check_ajax_referer( 'inlineeditnonce', '_inline_edit' )` in wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php:1318. thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: aww i can't upvote you!

Comment: No problem! You can mark the answer as accepted.